# Laravel eloquent insert query fails to catch values from input

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using eloquent and auth in laravel to register and login users, but I'm having trouble in the create function of the register controller. The problem is that it fails to make the insert because of a field that does not have a default value (which means that as it couldn't get any value for that field, it tries to get the default and if it doesn't have one, it fails. 
This is the controller code :

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
  //   terminar validacion

    //dd($data['nacimiento']);
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
        'nacimiento' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d"|required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6|'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if(!isset($data['avisos'])){
      $data['avisos'] = 0;
    }
    if(!isset($data['actualizaciones'])){
      $data['actualizaciones'] = 0;
    }
    if(!isset($data['ofertas'])){
      $data['ofertas'] = 0;
    }
  //  dd($data);
    dd(User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'nacimiento' => $data['nacimiento'],
        'suscAvisos' => $data['avisos'],
        'suscOfertas' => $data['ofertas'],
        'suscActualizaciones' => $data['actualizaciones'],
    ]));
}
```

and this is the form in my register view.

```
    <form action="/register" method="POST" class='form-reg'>
  {{ csrf_field() }}
    <fieldset class="datos">
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      <span class="error">{{ $error }}</span> <br>
      @endforeach
        <label>
            Nombre
            <input type="text" name="name" value=''  class="name">
        </label>
        <label>
            Apellido
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value=''  class="apellido">
        </label>
        <label>
            Email
            <input type="email" name="email" value='' class="mail">
        </label>
        <label>
            Fecha de nacimiento
            <input type="date" name="nacimiento" value='' class="birthday">
        </label>
        <label>
            Contraseña
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="password">
        </label>
        <label>
            Repetir la contraseña
            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" value="" class="passwordRepeat">
        </label>
        <section class="suscripciones">
            <div clas="susc">
                <input type="checkbox" name="avisos" value="1" class="checks">
                <div class="susc-datos">
                    <h6>Avisos</h6>
                    <p>Recibir avisos, recomendaciones y actualizaciones sobre productos, servicios, actualizaciones de Nexround y más.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="susc">
                <input type="checkbox" name="ofertas" value="1" class="checks">
                <div class="susc-datos">
                    <h6>Ofertas de Nexround</h6>
                    <p>Recibir recomendaciones, lo más reciente, ofertas especiales y contenido exclusivo y más.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="susc">
                <input type="checkbox" name="actualizaciones" value="1" class="checks">
                <div class="susc-datos">
                    <h6>Actualizaciones de Nexround News</h6>
                    <p>Recibe los mejores artículos y recomendaciones de Noticias de Nexround enviadas directamente a tu bandeja de entrada.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <button type='submit' class="continuar-boton">Registrar</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

The error shows this -

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'nacimiento' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into 'users' ('name', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'suscAvisos', 'suscOfertas', 'suscActualizaciones', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (fela, bird, fela_917@hotmail.com, $2y$10$SrvLDve6tJS/cLd5vWLK/eCwp1T/x4sIUcLelUpgFxvcSqNCfC7KW, 0, 0, 0, 2016-12-09 18:25:48, 2016-12-09 18:25:48))

I know what the error means and why is it caused, but I just can't find the error and why the query doesn't have my `nacimiento` value.
I debug both create and validate functions to see if `data['nacimiento']` had something, and it does. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Is `nacimiento` in the `$fillable` array for the User model?

Comment: Are you using migrations to make your table?  Please post your user table migration if so.  You may need to check `nacimento` is nullable.

Comment: omg, nacimiento wasnt on the fillable. Damn im dumb. Thanks for the help!!! REALLY!

Answer (score 0):

The problema was that 'nacimiento' wasnt in the $fillable variable. Thanks Devon.

Comment: No problem, when using mass assignment methods like create or update, you'll need the fields to either be included in `$fillable` or excluded from `$guarded`.

Answer (score -4):

PLEASE CHANGE YOUR DATABASE SCHEMA ASSIGNED 'nacimiento' COLUMN TO DEFAULT VALUE
OR CHANGE IT TO DEFAULT NULL

Comment: That's a poor way to fix the problem, maybe they don't want a default value or a null value in this column.   They were already assigning it in the problem.